# call a php upon clicking a hyperlink

Tags: php

it is to be checked if a user is logged in before directing to another page after clicking on a hyperlink.

for example :

```
if(isset($_POST[...])
   foo1(..);
else 
   foo2(..);
```

Thank you

Comment: PHP works on server, hyperlink is in browser on client

Comment: @zerkms i know that , what alternative ways can be used?

Answer (score 2):

Check in the other page...

Example, you want access:
yoursite.com/restrcited.php

Link to that page and when the user access,
check if he is logged:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged']) and $_SESSION['is_logged'])){ 
/* show the content here*/
}else{
header('Location: /login.php?err=');
}
```

If the user is logged, he'll see the content, else, he will be redirected to login...
You can't do it in another way using client-side (for security reasons)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is this:

1. The user clicks on a link
2. PHP checks to see if they're logged in
3. If so, it directs them to a particular page. (and if not, to a different page?)

So just have the link take them to a PHP page that does whatever you need to do to find out if they're logged in. Then:

```
if($loggedin) {
    header(' Location:http://yoursite.net/page_you_requested.html ');
}
else {
    header(' Location:http://yoursite.net/login_page.html ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some kind of trick with jQuery and also simple javascript, take a look...

Try to define this variable for session when a user gets logged:

```
//method that validates user and password from user and returns true or false
if(validateUserExample($user, $pwd)){
   //if the data of the user is correct (user and password) set the session of user logged
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user_logged'] = true;
}
```

1 - Make a php file called "myfile.php":

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //if there is no user logged redirect to index.
    if($_SESSION['user_logged'] != true)
    {
        header("location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

2 - Set your input button

```
<input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="Click Me" />
```

3 - In your .js file the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
         location.href = 'myfile.php';
    });
});
```

When you click on "btn" it will redirect to myfile.php that will take a look if the user is logged or not and then you got what you expect (I think)

Hope this helps :-)

PS. Please read more and understand server side and client side for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to set up the post to post to a page which includes the php function.  This is all because PHP runs at the server and not the client.

Answer (score 0):

what you describe requires a php script on the server that checks for logged in status and then does the redirect to the other page.  I'll suggest an alternative method that will work a little nicer.

Create a php "security" script.  All it does is check the login status.  If you're logged in, continue execution; if you're not, die() or redirect to an error/login page.

In all pages that require a login, include the security script.  Then link to these pages as normal.  If the user is logged in your links work as expected and no extra tricks are required to navigate.  Be sure to offer a login page to users so they have a good experience while navigating your site.